Open Graph doesn't read meta tags in Facebook Messenger
Open Graph data is not showing when I'm sharing my NextJs website's url (https://www.casadebambu.ph/) via Facebook Messenger when sending it to other people. But it is visible in my own chatbox, in my Facebook post and in the Sharing Debugger.
Sending to another person's Messenger:

Sending to own chatbox:

Posting in Facebook profile:

Sharing Debugger:

Here's the metadata in the website's header;
<meta property="og:title" content="Casa de Bambu — Farm Resort in Antipolo, Rizal">
<meta property="og:description" content="Experience a tranquil getaway in the idyllic countryside of Antipolo, Rizal at Casa de Bambu, offering relaxing accommodations, pet-friendly facilities, and lush green surroundings.">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.casadebambu.ph/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Casa de Bambu — Farm Resort in Antipolo, Rizal">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.casadebambu.ph/images/casa-de-bambu-fb-og.png">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">

I tried to use the Sharing Debugger but the meta data seems to be visible. I also tried replicating it in a different Facebook account but the issue still persists.
I saw this question in Meta for Developers Community, but it's still unanswered.
I don't know if this is an isolated case, but I'm looking for someone that might have encountered this and resolved it.
